# UIAlertController creation in global method

Tags: swift, uialertcontroller

I have a few four lines blocks as below in my app to decide flow based on user's Yes or No action

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Delete", message: "Really delete?", preferredStyle: .alert)
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Yes", style: .destructive, handler: {(action) in self.deleteHistoryRecord(forRecordID: self.shistIDs[indexPath.row])}))
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "No", style: .default, handler: nil))
self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

I'd like to create global app method/function with first three lines and returning Yes/No flag back. What's the best way to manage hander closure to call proper method in caller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to have a global function able to show the alert, you might use an extension like this one:

```
extension UIViewController {
  func showAlert(_ completion:@escaping ()->()) {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Delete", message: "Really delete?", preferredStyle: .alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Yes", style: .destructive, handler: { (action) in
      completion()
    }))
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "No", style: .default, handler: nil))
    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
  }
}
```

and then whenever you need to show the alert you just call `showAlert` passing the completion you would like to be executed (in case of Yes); eg: from your `ViewController` you might use this:

```
self.showAlert {
  self.deleteHistoryRecord(forRecordID: self.shistIDs[indexPath.row])
}
```

Comment: Excellent, thanks. That`s what I wanted.